# How to use antlr4 parser functions in a visitor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antlr, antlr4

I am currently trying to build a React project that tests antlr4 grammars and help me with further development. The program is running without any problems, but now I have implemented a visitor. This was created using antlr4 and the -visitor parameter. In my parser I have two production rules:

```js
    FIELD() {
            return this.getToken(ExampleParser.FELDNAME, 0);
        };

    INTEGER = function(i) {
        if(i===undefined) {
            i = null;
        }
           if(i===null) {
               return this.getTokens(ExampleParser.INTEGER);
           } else {
               return this.getToken(ExampleParser.INTEGER, i);
           }
    };
```

These two I want to use later in my Visitor. So in React I initialized the Visitor with the parser:

```js
    const onSubmit = data => {
        console.clear();
        const listener = new ExampleListener();
        const chars = new antlr4.InputStream(data.stringToLex);
        const parser = getParserInstance(selected, chars);
        
        parser.buildParseTrees = true;
        parser.strictMode = true;
      
        const visitor = new ExampleParserVisitor(parser); // Parser-Reference
      
        let tree = null;

        parser.addParseListener(listener);
        tree = parser.start();
        const stringTree = tree.toStringTree();
        const treeVisitResult = visitor.visitRight(tree);
        document.getElementById('outputText').value = stringTree + "\n\nResult: " + treeVisitResult;
    };
```

In my Visitor file, I created a constructor to intercept the parser and provide me with the functions:

```js
    export default class ExampleParserVisitor extends antlr4.tree.ParseTreeVisitor {
        constructor(parser) {
            super();
            this.parser = parser;
        }
      
        //Visit functions here... like in the following code snippet
    }
```

If I now want to use these functions in a visit function from my visit file, they are not recognized:

```js
    visitRight(ctx) {
      const field = this.parser.FIELD();
      const integer = this.parser.INTEGER();
      return field + " " + integer;
    }
```

> Error Message: FIELD() is not a function.
> (Of course INTEGER() also doesn't work)

My Input is for example RIGHT(Hello;3) ... the FIELD should be Hello and the INTEGER 3 in best case. The grammars are fine and are **not** the problem

Where could be my error? I am sorry that I cannot provide an example that reproduces the error.

Comment: Perhaps you'll get better feedback is you post your grammar (or a stripped down grammar that demonstrates the issue.  Your first code block does not look like anything I'd expect to see in a grammar.  Also, in general, by the time you get a parse tree back from the parser, you're done with it (the parser).  Having a visitor call methods on the parser is probably misguided.

Comment: @MikeCargal how would you call these methods? Out of context object? For example ctx.FIELD()?

Comment: @MikeCargal I just don't understand how to access the leaves of my tree in the visitor. Like getChildCount() only gives me 1 back, even if the input is RIGHT(Hello;3)... it should be 3... Hello / ; / 3 ... that's why I need something like ctx.FIELD() and ctx.INTEGER() to access my leaves

Comment: Your Context classes should have methods that give access to your child nodes.  If you post a sample grammar, I could produce a more specific answer to your question.  You won't have to define your own methods to access child nodes.